# Performance of log4j2 compared to log4j1

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to migrate my app into using log4j2. It is currently using log4j 1.2.16. I also have a performance build for my project, and after upgrading to log4j 2, the performance seemed to have improve a lot.

That is, until I read about bridging. According to the doc, I have to exclude log4j1 JAR from the classpath, and include the bridging JAR - which I assume is named 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api'. Once I did this, performance dropped again.

So to summarise:

1. Performance with log4j2 + bridging jar + log4j-1.2-api + log4j1 : good
2. Performance with log4j2 + bridging jar + log4j-1.2-api : bad (to the point that it drops back to performance of just log4j1)

I have checked that the log4j-1.2-api is earlier in the classpath. So it should have been loaded first.

Any idea what could cause this problem?

Thank you very much in advance!

Oh my complete classpath for logging are:

- org.slf4j:slf4j-api
- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j
- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j
- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl
- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core
- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api
- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-1.2-api
- log4j:log4j  (with & without, as described above)

Versions:

- Log4j2 : 2.6.2
- slf4j: 1.7.20
- log4j1: 1.2.16

My config file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration
        xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

    <xi:include href="log4j2-xinclude-appenders.xml" />

    <Loggers>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="rollingFileAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="stdOutAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And the log4j2-xinclude-appenders.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<appenders>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="_rollingFileAppender" fileName="./logs/foo-${sys:app.name.suffix}.log"
                 filePattern="./logs/foo-${sys:foo.app.name.suffix}.log.%i">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d|%X{active.profiles}| %-5p |%X{fcp.session}|%X{StateMachine.key}|%X{StateMachine.currentState}| %m | %t | %c{1.}%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="0" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>

    <Async name="rollingFileAppender" blocking="false" bufferSize="10000">
        <AppenderRef ref="_rollingFileAppender"/>
    </Async>

    <Console  name="_stdOutAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d|%X{active.profiles}| %-5p |%X{fcp.session}|%X{StateMachine.key}|%X{StateMachine.currentState}| %m | %t | %c{1.}%n"/>
    </Console>     
    <Async name="stdOutAppender" blocking="false" bufferSize="10000">
        <AppenderRef ref="_stdOutAppender"/>
    </Async>
</appenders>
```

**EDIT:** This is the log4j 1 xml file that gets included in the classpath

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration debug="false" xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="A1" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="R" class="com.bar.common.util.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="./logs/bar.log"/>
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="100MB"/>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10"/>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Performance Appender -->
    <appender name="OneSecondStatsAppender"
              class="com.foo.perf.AggregatedStatisticsAppender">
        <param name="TimeSlice" value="1000"/>
        <appender-ref ref="OneSecondStatsLogger"/>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FiveMinuteStatsAppender"
              class="com.bar.perf.DatafabricAggregatedStatisticsAppender">
        <param name="TimeSlice" value="300000"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FiveMinuteStatsLogger"/>
    </appender>

    <!-- Aggregated Performance Statistics Appender -->
    <appender name="OneSecondStatsLogger" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="./logs/bar-performance.log"/>
        <layout class="com.bar.perf.AggregatedStatisticsCsvLayout"/>
        <filter class="com.bar.perf.CategorisedStatisticExclusionFilter"/>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FiveMinuteStatsLogger" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="./logs/bar-minutes.log"/>
        <layout class="com.bar.perf.AggregatedStatisticsCsvLayout">
            <param name="ShowEmptyStatistics" value="true"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.perf4j.TimingLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="OneSecondStatsAppender"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FiveMinuteStatsAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.bar">
        <level value="INFO"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="com.gemstone.gemfire">
        <level value="INFO"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.data">
        <level value="INFO"/>
    </logger>

    <!-- Root logger configuration -->
    <root>
        <priority value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="R"/>
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

**EDIT 2**:
Classpath order for poor performance:

```
log4j-1.2-api-2.6.2.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.20.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.20.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar
log4j-core-2.6.2.jar
log4j-api-2.6.2.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

Classpath order for good performance

```
log4j-1.2-api-2.6.2.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.20.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.20.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.20.jar
log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar
log4j-core-2.6.2.jar
log4j-api-2.6.2.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

Comment: When you say "bridging jar + log4j-1.2-api", what do you mean? Aren't these the same thing?

Comment: Exactly. They are the same. But the log4j 2 documentation specifically says "bridge jar" : https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/log4j-1.2-api/index.html .  I was initially confused too!

Comment: Hi, I would like to know how did you test the performance of the application. What parameters did you take under consideration and why do you need log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.20.

Answer (score 0):

I there there are two questions here:

1. Why does log4j 1 get used in certain classpath configurations
2. Why is log4j 2 not faster than log4j 1

**1. Why is log4j 1 used**

I suspect that the following slf4j dependencies caused the old log4j 1.2 to be used:

```
org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j
org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j
```

If you use maven these could bring in the old Log4j 1 as a transitive dependency even if you don't explicitly declare it in your POM.

Please remove these. Log4j 2 has log4j-slf4j-impl and log4j-jcl modules that will accomplish the same but use Log4j 2 instead.

You should not have Log4j 1 in the classpath. If your application (or any of the libraries you use) depend on the Log4j 1 API, then add the log4j-1.2-api module.

**2. Why is log4j 2 not faster than log4j 1**

The configuration you describe does not take advantage of log4j 2 features. It uses AsyncAppender (which is roughly equivalent in log4j 1 and 2) and ConsoleAppender (which is slightly worse in log4j 2). [ConsoleAppender is about 60 times slower](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/performance.html#tradeoffs) than file appender. Be extremely careful when logging to the console in production systems.

Here is what I suggest: **remove** the following (which now seems to give better performance, but bear with me)

- log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.20
- log4j-1.2.16
- the old lo4j.xml configuration

**Add** the LMAX Disruptor dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lmax/disruptor -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lmax</groupId>
    <artifactId>disruptor</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Use the following log4j2.xml configuration. Temporarily just make it a simple file without includes, you can put that back later. (Notice I added `<Configuration status="trace"` to the beginning of the file: that will output internal log4j2 debugging statements so you can confirm that configuration completed without problems.)

Note that I made Console logging WARN level as I suspect it is impacting performance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="TRACE" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">

  <appenders>
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="_rollingFileAppender" 
                 fileName="./logs/foo-${sys:app.name.suffix}.log"
                 filePattern="./logs/foo-${sys:foo.app.name.suffix}.log.%i">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d|%X{active.profiles}| %-5p |%X{fcp.session}|%X{StateMachine.key}|%X{StateMachine.currentState}| %m | %t | %c{1.}%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy minSize="0" />
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>

    <Console  name="_stdOutAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d|%X{active.profiles}| %-5p |%X{fcp.session}|%X{StateMachine.key}|%X{StateMachine.currentState}| %m | %t | %c{1.}%n"/>
    </Console>     
  </appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="_rollingFileAppender"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="_stdOutAppender" level="WARN" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Now, the final (key) point: **enable log4j 2 [async loggers](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#AllAsync)** by setting system property `Log4jContextSelector` to `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector`.

This last bit should make a large performance difference. (Together with disabling Console logging.)

Comment: Hi Remko. I can try to remove them. However, when I include log4j 1 JAR, the performance was much better.  So, as I've mentioned, my app is consistently performing better with log4j-1.2-api _plus_ log4j1 JAR. Pretty sure log4j-1.2-api is used, as it is listed earlier in the classpath. I've also checked which Logger class is being used, and I can confirm that the one from log4j-1.2.api is the one being used. However.. this JAR doesn't contain all the classes from log4j 1 JAR. Which makes me wonder if there's any 'leftover' classes being referenced from somewhere..

Comment: Thanks again Remko. I've edited my original post to include these.

Comment: Interesting. Log4j 2's AsyncAppender performance is not that different from Log4j 1. (Async Loggers are much better, performance-wise.) It could be the benefit of garbagefree logging (the queue is emptied faster so less waiting when the queue is full). Not sure what is going on here. Can you confirm which Log4j 1 jar is actually used by printing the result of `org.apache.log4j.Logger.class.getResource("/org/apache/log4j/Logger.class");`?

Comment: Also, is there an old-style log4j.xml or log4j.properties config file in the classpath? You can check with `System.out.println(org.apache.log4j.Logger.class.getResource("/log4j.xml"));`

Comment: The Logger class used is: jar:file:/teamcity/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-1.2-api/2.6.2/log4j-1.2-api-2.6.2.jar!/org/apache/log4j/Logger.cl
ass

Comment: There is log4j.xml in the classpath, in a JAR that has been included... I will add the log4j.xml in the original post

Comment: Having said that, Remko... this log4j1 xml file shouldnt be used, right? The logger class being referenced is from the bridging jar...

Comment: The log4j-1.2-api jar doesn't contain _all_ classes that are in log4j-1.2.x. Old config _may_ get loaded. I'm still uneasy about having both jars on the classpath. Unpredictable.

Comment: How do you measure and what are the numbers you are seeing?

Comment: Hmm.. it is not straight forward to explain here. My perf test is not testing log4j performance per se. It is perf for the application as a whole. I saw performance improvement of about 40% after swapping to log4j2. At this time I didnt realise that log4j 1 was in the classpath. I then took out log4j 1, and perf dropped back to what it was. The app itself is a trading platform. I measured the quote latency that the client receives. Performance difference was from 900ms -> 500ms.

Comment: Try switching to making all loggers async & take out the AsyncAppenders. Should improve things. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#AllAsync

Comment: Thanks again for that. I havent got time to switch the config to Async logger. But I find something that is quite interesting. I took out log4j-over-slf4j JAR, leaving log4j 1 JAR, and the performance drops! So... both (1) taking log4j1 JAR and (2) taking log4j-over-slf4j JAR causes performance drops.  I'll update the original post with the order of the JAR in the classpath.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124547/discussion-between-caffeine-inquisitor-and-remko-popma).

Comment: I expanded my answer.

Comment: Thanks for that Remko. Tell me if I'm wrong here, but I've enabled -verbose:class JVM option which should print which classes were loaded from which JAR. Nothing gets loaded from those two JAR (org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j and  log4j 1). We are also on the same page on excluding those JARs from the classpath. I just cant see how excluding them causes performance drop though. Anyway... from what you were saying, it seems that I'm not going to get much perf gain with just async appender? I might have to give this more consideration (switching to async logger)

Comment: AsyncAppender performance between Log4j 1 and 2 is roughly equivalent. Please see https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#Performance for details and for an idea on how much better Async Loggers will be.

Comment: Thanks Remko. I have tried enabling async logger as per your recommendation. The performance didn't change at all. :9 maybe my issue is somewhere else. Interesting to know what causes that perf gain though! :D

Comment: Really? Something went wrong... Can you try changing `Root` to `AsyncRoot` in the configuration? I'm convinced you should see an improvement.

Comment: Hi Remko. Apology for the late response. I've scheduled a couple more run of our perf test with changing Root to AsyncRoot. I didnt see any perf difference. So... yeah.. maybe our problem is elsewhere. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into more strange findings. I enabled '-verbose:class' JVM options to see which classes were loaded, and I can confirm that only classes from the following JARs were loaded (in the order):

- slf4j-api-1.7.20.jar
- log4j-slf4j-impl-2.6.2.jar
- log4j-api-2.6.2.jar
- log4j-core-2.6.2.jar
- log4j-1.2-api-2.6.2.jar
- jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.20.jar

Yet, the following two tests yield different result:

1. Performance test with including log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.20 & log4j-1.2.16 : 
   GOOD
2. Performance test with including log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.20 & but excluding log4j-1.2.16 : BAD
3. Performance test with excluding log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.20 & including log4j-1.2.16 : BAD

Note that these two JARs were not loaded at all.